# Asignación de valor booleano a una variable a partir de un arreglo con una operación

Tags: javascript

Tengo este arreglo:

```
var prop = ["(",true,"&&",false,")","||","!",true];
```

Como ven, es una operación lógica y necesito extraer su valor de verdad para ponerlo en otra variable, como si tuviera esto:

```
var resultado = (true && false) || !true;
```

con lo que el valor de la variable "resultado" quedaría en "false".

para construir la operación necesitaría convertir todos esos strings  "(" , ")" , "&&" , "||" , "!" a los operadores reales que son para poder utilizarlos al igual que en la variable "resultado", y es eso lo que no sé cómo hacer.

Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @Roberto. Te recomiendo que aceptes una respuesta, de preferencia la que crees que más te ha ayudado a resolver tu problema.

Comment: están las dos buenas >< quisiera aceptarlas las dos, bueno gracias por recordármelo.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo Como comentario adicional a las respuestas quiero decirte que usar `eval` no es recomendado a menos que estes haciendo un interprete, un motor de plantillas o algo similar. Estos son casos extremos y el uso de esa función esta plenamente justificado. La razón de esto es porque eval te desactiva todas las optimizaciónes que le hace el navegador al código que ejecutas, crea vulnerabilidades de seguridad y tiene algunos casos donde el código que evalúas no se comporta como esperas. Espero que leas un poco más al respecto para que veas porque. Suerte.

Comment: muchas gracias, estaré investigando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar el método join del objeto Array para crear una cadena con la expresión y a continuación utilizar el método eval para evaluarla:

```js
var prop = ["(",true,"&&",false,")","||","!",true];

var resultado = eval(prop.join(' '));

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, una respuesta concisa, me ha sido de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes hacerlo de una manera sencilla en dos simples pasos:

1. Transforma el array en una cadena usando `join`
2. Evalúa el resultado de la cadena generada usando `eval`

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var prop = ["(",true,"&&",false,")","||","!",true];
var aux  = prop.join("");
console.log("La cadena lógica que se ejecutará: " + aux);
var res  = eval(aux);
console.log("El resultado es: " + res);
```

> Nota: el uso de `eval` no es recomendado si va a ser con entradas del usuario

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha sido de gran ayuda.